# Catch all ajax requests (grid refresh) using HtmlUnit

Tags: java, ajax, htmlunit

I am scrapping a website with this workflow process using HtmlUnit library.

1. Goes to root site like [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com)
2. Do login ([www.mysite.com/login](http://www.mysite.com/login))
3. Access to a page where table/grid is located ([www.mysite.com/list](http://www.mysite.com/list))

In the last point, a table is present and is being refreshed from the server every 30s. I find those ajax requests (fecth/XHR) in chrome network developer tool, with ([www.mysite.com/events](http://www.mysite.com/events)) endpoint. My first approach was make a simple http connection/request after the login, but unfortunately the payload of this request is very complex and have dynamic information that i can't reproduce to apply it.

So my second approach is listen request every time the server issues.

i am doing in that way

```
 //webclient instance config

 webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
 webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
 webClient.getOptions().setDoNotTrackEnabled(false);
 webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
 webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());

 // do login

 HtmlPage loginPage = webClient.getPage("www.mysite.com/login");
 HtmlForm form = loginPage.getForms().get(0);
 form.getInputByName("email").type(username);
 form.getInputByName("password").type(password);
 HtmlButton button = (HtmlButton) loginPage.getElementById("submit");
 button.click();

 // listen ajax requests on www.mysite.com/list

 new WebConnectionWrapper(webClient) {
            @Override
            public WebResponse getResponse(final WebRequest request) throws IOException {
                final WebResponse response = super.getResponse(request);
                logger.info(request.getUrl().toString());
                return response;
            }
        };

  webClient.getPage("www.mysite.com/list");
  webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(7000);
```

But i am not able to catch the ajax request (/events URI) that brings this data to refresh the grid

Is something missing? Thanks

Comment: Do you have a sample url to reproduce your case

Comment: the connection wrapper is not used if the request is already in the cache - try to set the connection wrapper as part of your general webclient setup before the first getPage() call

Comment: thanks for your feedback :) . For example, https://js-tutorials.com/demos/jqgrid_jquery_example_demo/ can be serve as a example. If i get this url, will returm me a html page without data populated to grid but after that a ajax request is done with https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_search=false&nd=1677683438536&rows=10&page=1&sidx=id&sord=desc . 
My goal is handling that ajax response value/data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works here (HtmlUnit 2.70.0)

```
String url = "https://js-tutorials.com/demos/jqgrid_jquery_example_demo/";

try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

    new WebConnectionWrapper(webClient) {
        @Override
        public WebResponse getResponse(final WebRequest request) throws IOException {
            final WebResponse response = super.getResponse(request);

            System.out.println(request.getUrl().toString());

            if (request.getUrl().toString().startsWith("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")) {
                System.out.println("-----");
                System.out.println(response.getContentAsString());
                System.out.println("-----");
            }
            return response;
        }
    };

    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10_000);
    page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getCurrentWindow().getEnclosedPage();

    System.out.println("----------------");
    System.out.println(page.asNormalizedText());
    System.out.println("----------------");
}
```

}